# How do i print the reverse of name in python without using function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose i have enter a `input` `john doe garry`
and i want to print `garry doe john`

I have attempted this many times:

```
for x in range(0,l-1):
    first  = first+' '+li[i][0]
    i-=1
first=li[l-1]+' '+first
print(first)
```

but it's not getting me output as I expected

Comment: "without using function?" You mean without using `print`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi mannish it's look like little bit improvement in your code

```
na = input('enter your name ')
li=na.split()
li = na.split()
l=len(li)
i=0

for x in range(0,l):
   first=first+' '+li[i-1]
   k-=1
first=first
print(first)
```

if your input is `john doe garry` then output is.

`garry doe john` i hope its working for you Thanks.

Comment: its code also help the beginners in python. Thanks buddy great job

Comment: its my pleasure to do that

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following: split the input, reverse the tokens using the `[::-1]` slice, and `join` them back together.

```
input = 'john doe garry'
rev = ' '.join(input.split()[::-1])
print(rev)
# garry doe john
```

Comment: i say without using any helping function

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to `print`:

```
first = input()
for i in first.split()[::-1]:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

> ```
> doegarryjohn(xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 reverse.py
> john garry doe
> doe garry john
> ```

If you would like to store it as a variable:

```
first = input()
f_reverse = ''
for i in first.split()[::-1]:
        f_reverse += (i + ' ')

print(f_reverse)
```